# Multiplication algorithm slower than expected

Tags: performance, rust, benchmarking

I am playing around with Rust while reading *From Mathematics To Generic Programming* by Stepanov & Rose.

In the first chapter of the book the authors optimize integer multiplication algorithms starting with a trivial approach and ending with a highly optimized one (`mul0` to `mul4`).

I implemented the discussed algorithms in Rust and benchmarked them with `cargo bench`. To my surprise, the fastest in algorithm from the book is by far the slowest in the benchmark and I have no idea how this can be. The usual suspect is compiler optimization but I do not have enough assembly skills to check the binary by hand.

Why is this the case?

```
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;

fn mul_acc4(a: i32, b: i32, r: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut r = r;
    let mut a = a;
    let mut b = b;

    loop {
        if odd(a) {
            r = r + b;

            if a == 1 {
                return r;
            }
        }

        a = half(a);
        b = b + b;
    }
}

fn mul0(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    if a == 1 {
        return b;
    }

    return mul0(a - 1, b) + b;
}

fn mul2(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    if a == 1 {
        return b;
    }

    return mul_acc4(b, a - 1, b);
}

fn mul4(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut a = a;
    let mut b = b;

    while !odd(a) {
        b = b + b;
        a = half(a);
    }

    if a == 1 {
        return b;
    }

    return mul_acc4(b + b, half(a - 1), b);
}

fn half(a: i32) -> i32 {
    a >> 1
}

fn odd(a: i32) -> bool {
    a & 0x1 == 1
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    use super::*;
    use test::{black_box, Bencher};

    #[bench]
    fn bench_mul0(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let arg = 42000;
            let mut acc = 0;

            for i in 1..1000 {
                acc += mul0(arg, i);
            }

            return acc;
        });
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_mul2(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let arg = 42000;
            let mut acc = 0;
            for i in 1..1000 {
                acc += mul2(arg, i);
            }

            return acc;
        });
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_mul4(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let arg = 42000;
            let mut acc = 0;
            for i in 1..1000 {
                acc += mul4(arg, i);
            }

            return acc;
        });
    }
}
```

**Benchmark Results**

```
tests::bench_mul0 ... bench:           0 ns/iter (+/- 0) test
tests::bench_mul2 ... bench:      15,535 ns/iter (+/- 6,887) test
tests::bench_mul4 ... bench:      29,015 ns/iter (+/- 9,168)
```

Comment: `0 ns/iter` means that the optimizer has removed your entire code and you are benchmarking "nothing". It's not actually faster.

Comment: `mul0` is optimized to a multiplication (`imul`), a move to put the result in `eax`, and a return.

Comment: Obviously none of these methods are fast compared to what's built-in to modern x86 hardware: 3-cycle latency even for 64-bit integer multiply, with 1 per clock throughput.  (And using only a single uop, so it can execute in parallel with ~3 other instructions.)  http://agner.org/optimize/.  These software implementations would be interesting on a CPU without hardware multiply, but even for extended-precision, building a wider multiply out of narrower multiply instructions is better than a shift / add bit loop like this.

Comment: @FrancisGagné: But then after inlining, the whole loop optimizes away, otherwise it would measure at least a `ns` per iteration or so.  (`call` / `imul` / `ret` + `add` + loop overhead would take more than 1 cycle per iteration, at least 3 for 3 taken branches (call/ret/ loop-branch) .  A clock cycle on a 3GHz CPU is 0.33 ns, so we should see at least 1ns.  Exactly 0 is much more easily explained by the whole loop optimizing away.

Comment: @PeterCordes You're right. When I wrap the call to `mul0` in `black_box`, I get times like `274 ns/iter (+/- 8)`.

Comment: @lwi You seem to have messed up the order of the parameters when calling `mul_acc4` in `mul2` and `mul4` (the fact that you changed the order and names of the parameters compared to the book makes this less obvious); you flipped `a` and `b`. I get much lower times if I change the calls to `mul_acc4(a - 1, b, b)` and `mul_acc4(half(a - 1), b + b, b)`, respectively, and `mul4` is now faster than `mul2`, as expected.

Comment: @FrancisGagné: Nice test.  Oh, I see `b.iter` itself contains a loop, so the "per iter" numbers aren't per multiplication, they're per 1000 multiplies.  So 0.274 ns per multiply tells me I was wrong about call/ret overhead: it's getting inlined, and you're probably bottlenecking on 1 per clock `imul` throughput, and your CPU averaged ~3.65GHz while running that benchmark.  If my other guesses are correct, like no more-aggressive optimizations like auto-vectorization :P

Comment: You guys are amazing (@FrancisGagné , @PeterCordes )! Learned alot from your discussion and fixed the parameter order. Thank you.

Comment: @PeterCordes pedantically, it's only 999 iterations; `1..1000` is an exclusive range (1, 2, ..., 998, 999).

Comment: @lwi For what it's worth, [here's a more idiomatic version of your code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=282fc1bb64291eca1690126a3170c418&version=stable)